# Executed chmod -R 777 to home directory by accident, remedy?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod, home

I accidentally ran chmod -R 777 to my home directory.
I don't feel the change, but I'm afraid something bad will happen without me knowing.

Is there a way to restore it to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Right now, your entire home directory is readable and modifiable (writable) to anybody on your computer.*

I like to restrict my permissions to the minimum: that is, only readable & writable to the owner, being me. This is what I use to set those permissions:

```
find /home/me -type d -exec chmod 0700 {} \;
find /home/me -type f -exec chmod 0600 {} \;
```

Please verify what these commands do before executing them.

According to me, the first one applies a `chmod` of `0700` to every directory in `/home/me`, whereas the second applies `0600` to every regular file (not directory).

The difference is the executable bit, which must be set to be able to traverse directories.

**Keep in mind that any executable files (scripts, for example) won’t get the executable bit set, you have to set those manually, like this:**

```
chmod 0700 /home/me/bin/my_favourite_script
```

or, if you prefer

```
chmod u+x /home/me/bin/my_favourite_script
```

Comment: thats work, thx. at least now my home directory is not open to all users